# How can we allocate max CPU usage to a python code at the time of run?

Tags: python

How can we allocate max CPU usage to a python code at the time of run? I have a script that takes 1hr to run on my local machine(16Gb RAM quad-core) , but takes 4hrs on a remote AWS machine with 32GB RAM and 8cores.

Comment: What python versions are you running? Is your local python consistent with python used in the AWS?

Comment: this article might be prove useful to you: 
https://superuser.com/questions/679679/how-to-increase-pythons-cpu-usage

Comment: @Laszlowaty Yes, the python version is consistent. The script does run on the AWS machine, but takes way longer than on the local machine.

Comment: by default python runs only on one core. if remote machine cores are slower, your script run slower.